# probability with combinations

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

A college math department consisting of 20 faculty members must choose a department head, an assistant department head, and a faculty senate representative. in how many ways can this be done?

Comment: ece could you please clarify how many spots are there and in what order should they be chosen?

Comment: sorry about mistakes. there are 3 spots a department head, an assistant department head, and a faculty senate representative out of 20 people.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find out how many combinations these three spots can be chosen.

Forgive me if I'm going to grossly oversimplify this. Let's assume you have a bag of marbles with 10 colors. You want to pick randomly 3 balls to put on your desk. To calculate how many combinations that could be and their separate chances, first do the probability of picking one color (let's say blue) which is 1/10. that leaves 9 balls, all of which now have a probability 1/9 of being chosen. You pick the second one (yellow) which leaves 8 balls, each of which have a 1/8 chance of being picked. finally you pick the last one (green) and you're done.

With 10 balls in the bag, they had 1/10 chance each. With 9 balls, each had 1/9 chance. Eight balls had 1/8 chance of being picked.

The combination is simply a multiplication of these fractions: 1/10 * 1/9 * 1/8 = 1/720

the 720 represents the total combinations of colored balls.
1/720 is the chance of achieving one of them.

So, with your example:

choosing the department head: 1/200 chance

choosing the assistant department head: 1/199 chance

choosing the faculty senate representative: 1/98 chance

200 * 199 * 198=7,880,400 combinations

1/7,880,400 is the chance of achieving one of these combinations.

postscript: the reason we reduce the denominator each step is because one person was already elected for a spot. he can't take several spots.

** Also this is assuming the numerator is always 1

Comment: sorry if that took a long time to write by the way

Comment: thank u so much right know I could understand the logic of the solving question.

Comment: just be careful of the way you apply the subtracting part; like if you were going to return the ball to the bag after picking it, the probability of picking the next ball will stay 1/10